# eclipse virgo with velocity java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.velocity.exception.VelocityException

Tags: osgi, velocity, eclipse-virgo

I am facing problem to integrate velocity with virgo. I used apache velocity with my web application. i am using

> com.springsource.org.apache.velocity-1.6.2.jar

please find my configurations below

MANIFEST.MF

```
Import-Package: 
 javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core;version="[1.2.0, 2.0.0)",
 javax.servlet;version="[3.0.0, 3.1.0)",
 org.eclipse.virgo.web.dm;version="[3.0.0, 4.0.0)",
 org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.config,
 com.singtel.gdl.services.open.service.util,
 org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation,
 org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping,
 org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping,
 org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server,
 org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter,
 org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method,
 org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj,
 org.springframework.ws.soap,
 com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1,
 org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11,
 org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity;version="[3.0, 3.5)",
 org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp,
 org.apache.velocity.exception

Import-Bundle: 
 com.springsource.org.apache.taglibs.standard;version="[1.1.2,2.0)",
 gdl-model-rest-spec;version="[1.0.27.SNAPSHOT,2)",
 com.springsource.org.apache.velocity;version="[1.6.2,1.6.2]",
 org.apache.commons.lang;version="[2.6.0,2.6.0]",
 org.springframework.context;version="[3.0.5.RELEASE,3.2.5.RELEASE]",
 org.springframework.web;version="[3.0.5.RELEASE,3.2.5.RELEASE]"

Import-Library: 
 org.springframework.spring;version="[3.0, 3.5)"
```

Exception is

```
Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/open-sms-notification-ws-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/velocity/exception/VelocityException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$301(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.normalRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$NoDependenciesWaitRefreshExecutor.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.startWebApplication(TomcatServletContainer.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.StandardArtifactStateMonitor.onStarted(StandardArtifactStateMonitor.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.asyncStartSucceeded(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.access$0(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact$StateMonitorSignal.signalSuccessfulCompletion(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.core.internal.BundleStartTracker$1.run(BundleStartTracker.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/velocity/exception/VelocityException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1906)
```

I checked my osgi console with **ss** command, velocity library is already installed

```
osgi> ss
"Framework is launched."


id  State       Bundle
0   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944
                Fragments=1
35  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.userregionfactory_3.6.3.RELEASE
.
.
.
.
.
213 ACTIVE      org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-ws-addr_2.7.4
214 ACTIVE      org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-ws-security_2.7.6
215 ACTIVE      org.apache.santuario.xmlsec_1.5.1
216 ACTIVE      org.apache.ws.security.wss4j_1.6.11
217 ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.velocity_1.6.2
218 ACTIVE      cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution_1.3.0
219 ACTIVE      org.jvnet.staxex.stax-ex_1.7.4
220 ACTIVE      com.springsource.com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj_1.3.2
221 ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.xml.rpc_1.1.0.v20110517
224 ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.taglibs.standard_1.1.2.v20110517
225 ACTIVE      org.springframework.ws_2.1.0.RELEASE
226 ACTIVE      org.springframework.ws.xml_2.1.0.RELEASE
osgi>
```

Help me to solve this problem. This is dragging my work more than a days.

Thank-you in advance.
Gopy

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [Virgo Shell Commands](http://eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-3.6.3.RELEASE/docs/virgo-user-guide/html/ch08s02.html) described in this [blog](http://hsiliev.blogspot.de/2010/12/troubleshooting-class-loading-issues-in.html)
as suggested in our [FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Virgo/FAQ#How_can_I_diagnose_class_loading_problems.3F)?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I will explain more brief about issue. I removed all velocity related code from my project and i deployed velocity bundle finally deploy my web application, I am unable to deploy web application. Then i removed velocity bundle i tried to deploy web application which is successful

```
[2015-05-11 14:42:42.314] fs-watcher                   <HD0001I> Hot deployer processing 'CREATED' event for file 'org.apache.servicemix.bundles.velocity-1.7_6.jar'. 
[2015-05-11 14:42:42.481] fs-watcher                   <DE0000I> Installing bundle 'org.apache.servicemix.bundles.velocity' version '1.7.0.6'. 
[2015-05-11 14:42:42.551] fs-watcher                   <DE0001I> Installed bundle 'org.apache.servicemix.bundles.velocity' version '1.7.0.6'. 
[2015-05-11 14:42:42.558] fs-watcher                   <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'org.apache.servicemix.bundles.velocity' version '1.7.0.6'. 
[2015-05-11 14:42:42.562] start-signalling-2           <DE0005I> Started bundle 'org.apache.servicemix.bundles.velocity' version '1.7.0.6'. 




[2015-05-11 14:43:31.629] fs-watcher                   <HD0001I> Hot deployer processing 'MODIFIED' event for file 'demo-web.war'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:31.632] fs-watcher                   <DE0007I> Refreshing bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:31.686] fs-watcher                   <WE0002I> Stopping web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:31.688] fs-watcher                   <WE0002I> Stopping web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:32.544] fs-watcher                   <WE0003I> Stopped web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:32.546] fs-watcher                   <WE0003I> Stopped web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:32.548] fs-watcher                   <DE0010I> Stopping bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:32.552] fs-watcher                   <DE0011I> Stopped bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:32.654] fs-watcher                   <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:32.657] start-signalling-2           <WE0000I> Starting web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:32.658] start-signalling-2           <WE0000I> Starting web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:38.854] start-signalling-2           <WE0001I> Started web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:38.856] start-signalling-2           <WE0001I> Started web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:38.857] start-signalling-2           <WE0000I> Starting web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:38.858] start-signalling-2           <WE0000I> Starting web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:38.864] start-signalling-2           <WE0004E> Failed to start web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT': a web application with context path '/demo-web' already exists. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:38.866] start-signalling-2           <WE0004E> Failed to start web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT': a web application with context path '/demo-web' already exists. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:38.870] start-signalling-2           <DE0006E> Start failed for bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT'. org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.api.core.DeploymentException: Web application failed to start
    at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.StandardArtifactStateMonitor.onStarted(StandardArtifactStateMonitor.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.asyncStartSucceeded(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.access$0(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact$StateMonitorSignal.signalSuccessfulCompletion(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.core.internal.BundleStartTracker$1.run(BundleStartTracker.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.WebApplicationStartFailedException: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.spi.ContextPathExistsException: Context path '/demo-web' already exists
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:122)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.spi.ContextPathExistsException: Context path '/demo-web' already exists
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.checkContextPathIsFree(TomcatServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.startWebApplication(TomcatServletContainer.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:109)
    ... 9 common frames omitted

[2015-05-11 14:43:38.876] start-signalling-2           <WE0002I> Stopping web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:38.877] start-signalling-2           <WE0002I> Stopping web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:39.646] start-signalling-2           <WE0003I> Stopped web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:39.648] start-signalling-2           <WE0003I> Stopped web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:39.651] start-signalling-2           <WE0000I> Starting web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:39.653] start-signalling-2           <WE0000I> Starting web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:45.726] start-signalling-2           <WE0001I> Started web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:45.727] start-signalling-2           <WE0001I> Started web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:45.727] start-signalling-2           <WE0002I> Stopping web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:45.728] start-signalling-2           <WE0002I> Stopping web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:46.471] start-signalling-2           <WE0003I> Stopped web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:46.472] start-signalling-2           <WE0003I> Stopped web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:46.473] start-signalling-2           <DE0010I> Stopping bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:46.475] start-signalling-2           <DE0011I> Stopped bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:46.481] fs-watcher                   <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:46.484] start-signalling-2           <WE0000I> Starting web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:46.486] start-signalling-2           <WE0000I> Starting web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:52.463] start-signalling-2           <WE0001I> Started web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:52.464] start-signalling-2           <WE0001I> Started web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:52.465] start-signalling-2           <WE0000I> Starting web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:52.466] start-signalling-2           <WE0000I> Starting web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:52.470] start-signalling-2           <WE0004E> Failed to start web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT': a web application with context path '/demo-web' already exists. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:52.471] start-signalling-2           <WE0004E> Failed to start web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT': a web application with context path '/demo-web' already exists. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:52.474] start-signalling-2           <DE0006E> Start failed for bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT'. org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.api.core.DeploymentException: Web application failed to start
    at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.StandardArtifactStateMonitor.onStarted(StandardArtifactStateMonitor.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.asyncStartSucceeded(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.access$0(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact$StateMonitorSignal.signalSuccessfulCompletion(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.core.internal.BundleStartTracker$1.run(BundleStartTracker.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.WebApplicationStartFailedException: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.spi.ContextPathExistsException: Context path '/demo-web' already exists
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:122)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.spi.ContextPathExistsException: Context path '/demo-web' already exists
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.checkContextPathIsFree(TomcatServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.startWebApplication(TomcatServletContainer.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:109)
    ... 9 common frames omitted

[2015-05-11 14:43:52.478] start-signalling-2           <WE0002I> Stopping web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:52.479] start-signalling-2           <WE0002I> Stopping web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:53.214] start-signalling-2           <WE0003I> Stopped web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:53.216] start-signalling-2           <WE0003I> Stopped web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:53.217] start-signalling-2           <WE0000I> Starting web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:53.217] start-signalling-2           <WE0000I> Starting web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:59.108] start-signalling-2           <WE0001I> Started web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:59.109] start-signalling-2           <WE0001I> Started web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:59.110] start-signalling-2           <WE0002I> Stopping web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:59.111] start-signalling-2           <WE0002I> Stopping web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:59.849] start-signalling-2           <WE0003I> Stopped web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:59.850] start-signalling-2           <WE0003I> Stopped web bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT' with context path '/demo-web'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:59.851] start-signalling-2           <DE0010I> Stopping bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:59.853] start-signalling-2           <DE0011I> Stopped bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT'. 
[2015-05-11 14:43:59.872] fs-watcher                   <DE0009E> Refresh failed for bundle 'demo-web' version '1.0.1.SNAPSHOT'. org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.api.core.DeploymentException: Web application failed to start
    at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.StandardArtifactStateMonitor.onStarted(StandardArtifactStateMonitor.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.asyncStartSucceeded(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.access$0(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact$StateMonitorSignal.signalSuccessfulCompletion(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.core.internal.BundleStartTracker$1.run(BundleStartTracker.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.WebApplicationStartFailedException: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.spi.ContextPathExistsException: Context path '/demo-web' already exists
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:122)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.spi.ContextPathExistsException: Context path '/demo-web' already exists
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.checkContextPathIsFree(TomcatServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.startWebApplication(TomcatServletContainer.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:109)
    ... 9 common frames omitted

[2015-05-11 14:43:59.880] fs-watcher                   <HD0003E> Hot re-deploy failed for file 'demo-web.war'. org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.api.core.DeploymentException: Web application failed to start
    at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.StandardArtifactStateMonitor.onStarted(StandardArtifactStateMonitor.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.asyncStartSucceeded(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.access$0(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact$StateMonitorSignal.signalSuccessfulCompletion(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.core.internal.BundleStartTracker$1.run(BundleStartTracker.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.WebApplicationStartFailedException: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.spi.ContextPathExistsException: Context path '/demo-web' already exists
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:122)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.spi.ContextPathExistsException: Context path '/demo-web' already exists
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.checkContextPathIsFree(TomcatServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.startWebApplication(TomcatServletContainer.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:109)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

I have noticed demo-web bundle starting, started and stoped many times. I cannot get clue.

Regards,

Gopy